# How to add a special-character plugin with ckeditor by using CDN

Tags: ckeditor, cdn, ckeditor-plugin

I am working on a project where I am using `ckeditor` as CDN. Now I want to add the special-character plugin but I didn't find the official way.

I can't use the NPM way. I want to add the plugin by using the CDN link only.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>CKEditor</title>
        <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/40.2.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="editor">This is some sample content.</div>
        <script>
            ClassicEditor
            .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
                removePlugins: [ 'Heading', 'Indent', 'Link', 'CKFinder', 'EasyImage', 'Image', 'ImageCaption', 'ImageStyle', 'ImageToolbar', 'ImageUpload', 'Table', 'BlockQuote', 'MediaEmbed' ]
            })
            .catch( error => {
                console.error( error );
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```